# Scrapy: Login on webpage

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to log in on a webpage (let's call it example.com/a1J5AEAQ). First I will get an general page of example.com, and when I type in the username and password manually I get redirected to the right page. However, when I try to log in using scrapy I get redirected to 'somethingelse.com'

This is the first part of the html of the form: (after this only the fields for username and password are given)

```
    <form action="https://somethingelse.com/" id="login_form" method="post" name="login" onsubmit="return handleLogin();" target="_top">
                                <input name="un" type="hidden">
                                <input name="width" type="hidden">
                                <input name="height" type="hidden">
                                <input name="hasRememberUn" type="hidden" value="true">
                                <input name="local" type="hidden">
                                <input name="startURL" type="hidden" value="/a1J5AEAQ">
                                <input name="loginURL" type="hidden" value="http://www.example.com">
                                <input name="loginType" type="hidden">
                                <input name="useSecure" type="hidden" value="true">
                                <input name="lt" type="hidden" value="standard">
                                <input name="qs" type="hidden">
                                <input name="locale" type="hidden" value="uk">
                                <input name="oauth_token" type="hidden">
                                <input name="oauth_callback" type="hidden"><span id="j_id0:j_id1:j_id57:j_id60">
```

The code for my scrapy looks like this:

```
from scrapy.item import Item, Field
import scrapy

class LoginSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "webpages"
    start_urls = ["https://www.example.com/a1J5AEAQ"]
    def parse(self, response):
        return scrapy.FormRequest.from_response(
            response,
            formdata={'username': 'xxxxxx@xxxxxxxx.nl', 'pw': 'xxxxxxxxx'},
            formnumber=1,
            callback=self.after_login
        )

     def after_login(self, response):
        # print response.body
        # print response.status
        items = []
        # check login succeed before going on
        if 'Fout:' in response.body:
            print "\n\n Login failed \n\n"
            self.logger.error("Login failed")
        elif 'Please provide your username and password:' in response.body:
            print "\n\nstill on login page\n\n"
        else:
            print "\n\nWELL DONE\n\n"
            print response.body
            # scrape someting
        return items
```

My code prints "WELL DONE" because I am not on the the login page anymore, but I am on somethingelse.com instead (which I can see when I print the response.body). And that's not where I want to go.

If someone could help, that would be really great!

Comment: You'll notice that submitting this form in a browser will call some JavaScript code (`return handleLogin();`), which Scrapy does not interpret nor understands. I suggest that you inspect what a regular browser sends as HTTP headers and form data and try to replicate this with Scrapy.

Comment: @paultrmbrth I don't know that much about JavaScript. And I also don't know how to inspect what a regular browser sends as HTTP headers and form data. Any tips on where to start exploring this?

Comment: One usually looks at the "network" tab in a modern browser's developement tools panel. For example [in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/). You should be able to see to which URL that login POST is sent, and the HTTP headers that are sent along. These are the things that you should try to replicate with Scrapy `FormRequest`.